# Where is the Log4perl documentation for configuration?

Tags: perl, log4perl

I am new to the Perl and while doing with my new CR I stuck at the Perl code 
which is using [Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl) package.

Already developed code is using this package and in the configuration file of this package 
has this configuration:

```
log4perl.appender.Logfile.max  = 2
log4perl.appender.Logfile.size = 10_000
log4perl.appender.Logfile = Log::Dispatch::FileRotate
```

Can I get the information about these parameters in the configuration file, and perhaps change them?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can get information about those parameters. The [documentation for log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Log::Log4perl) should explain each of those.

Answer (score 1):

[Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl) is the Perl version of [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/). The documentation for either is often useful for the other since they are very close. If you have trouble with the docs, ask a more specific question with the parts you don't understand. :)

You might also want to see my chapter on Logging in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242/), which talks about the structure of the configuration files.